# Inconsistant data queried from postgres in two different go applications

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I've built two go applications, say **app1** and **app2**, they both connected to the same postgres database. For each application, I use *gorm* as ORM.

**app1** is used to update the databse and **app2** is an API server created in *gin* that queries data from the database.

In **app2** I create a database connection pool at the beginning of the program and it is reused in every HTTP endpoint handlers. Inside the handler function, I execute a SQL statement using *gorm* and returns the result.

The old return value of the SQL statement is like

`select count(*) from t_publications --returns--> 2641`

When I insert 4 new records in **app1**, I can get correct data both in **app1** and **psql** cli, so it's like

`select count(*) from t_publications --returns--> 2645`

However when I check the API endpoint of **app2**, which executes the same SQL statement, it returns the old data

`curl localhost:8080/getPublications --returns--> 2641`

If I restart **app2**, I can then get the correct data that I need. I'm not sure whether it is a problem regards to the lifetime of connections inside the connection pool, can someone explain this problem? Thanks.

----edit----

Here is one of my handler function for **app2**

```
func GetOverview(db *gorm.DB) gin.HandlerFunc {
    var overview Overview
    // the query is just a simple select statement
    err := db.Raw(dbquery.GetOverview).Scan(&overview).Error
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if err == nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
                "status": "ok",
                "data":   overview,
            })
        } else {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "status": "internal server error",
                "data":   err,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you open long lived transactions inside **app2**?

Comment: @Artur I don't open any mannual transactions in my code. I have edited my question and attached my handler function, you can check if there is any problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing the query exactly once in your `GetOverview` and then you're returning the result of that query in a closure that's used as the `gin.HandlerFunc`, essentially caching the result of the query, at the time of registering the handler, for ever.

The solution is to move the query code into the actual handler:

```
func GetOverview(db *gorm.DB) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var overview Overview
        // the query is just a simple select statement
        err := db.Raw(dbquery.GetOverview).Scan(&overview).Error
        if err == nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
                "status": "ok",
                "data":   overview,
            })
        } else {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "status": "internal server error",
                "data":   err,
            })
        }
    }
}
```